# Extract all changes of specific file from Git

Tags: git

Is there some quick and convenient way to extract all the commits of specific file from Git? Preferably to extract rather than view in log because Git does not show differences in UTF-16 encoded files.

I've made some change and now the task is to investigate when it was made. Please do not suggest to use Git history search even if it exists, because I do not know what exactly to search for.

Answer (score 0):

> I've made some change and now the task is to investigate when it was made.

In that case, I would use `git blame <filename>`. This will show you which commit each individual line was last changed in. Simply look for the line number(s) with the changes in question. If you have Tortoise-git, you can right click on the file and select "blame" for a nicer UI.

Comment: git blame cannot show information about differences in binary files. It treats UTF-16 encoded files as binaries.